How to Build a Custom Dropdown List Field That Retrieves the list from a Sitecore Bucket?
I am working on a Sitecore project and need to create a custom dropdown list field for Sitecore Forms that retrieves its options from an item bucket in Sitecore. Specifically, I want to populate the dropdown with items stored in a designated Sitecore bucket.

Which version of Sitecore do you use? Have you tried creating a custom form element as described in documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html?
